# Sometimes the program runs well, but sometimes the function select post an error that is Bad file descriptor

Tags: c

I make a program, two clients connect to a server, and one of the clients send msg to server, then the server resend this msg to another client.I use base_rdset as listen set, and rdset as ready set, clients' socket identifier storge in a array.
When I start the server, sometimes it runs well, but sometimes it posts an error which is `select:Bad file descriptor`. waht happend to this program?

```c
#include <55header.h>

#define SIZE 3

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    //./server 192.168.176.132 8080
    ARGS_CHECK(argc,3);

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;//ipv4
    addr.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[2]));//port
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);//ip

    int socket_fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    ERROR_CHECK(socket_fd,-1,"socket");

    int res_bind =bind(socket_fd,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(a
    ERROR_CHECK(res_bind,-1,"bind");

    int res_listen=listen(socket_fd,10);
    ERROR_CHECK(res_listen,-1,"listen");
    
    fd_set base_rdset;
    fd_set rdset;

    char buf[1024];
    int net_fds[SIZE]={0};
    FD_SET(socket_fd,&base_rdset);
    while(1){
        FD_ZERO(&rdset);
        memcpy(&rdset,&base_rdset,sizeof(base_rdset));
        int ready_num=select(10,&rdset,NULL,NULL,NULL);     
        ERROR_CHECK(ready_num,-1,"select");

        if(FD_ISSET(socket_fd,&rdset)){
            for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
                if(net_fds[i]==0){
                    net_fds[i]=accept(socket_fd,NULL,NULL);
                    FD_SET(net_fds[i],&base_rdset);
                    break;
                }         
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
            if(net_fds[i]==0){
                continue;
            }
            if(FD_ISSET(net_fds[i],&rdset)){
                memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf));
                int count_chars=recv(net_fds[i],buf,sizeof(bu
                ERROR_CHECK(count_chars,-1,"recv");
                if(count_chars==0){
                    close(net_fds[i]);
                    FD_CLR(net_fds[i],&base_rdset);
                    net_fds[i]=0;
                    continue;
                }
                for(int j=0;j<SIZE;j++){
                    if(j==i||net_fds[j]==0){
                        continue;
                    }
                    send(net_fds[j],buf,count_chars,0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

I add code that is`FD_ZERO(&base_rdset)`,this problem seems like be solved,but i am not sure,I want to know why does this error occered

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is to use a **uninitialized variable**. This is the relevant excerpt of your code (without the distracting comments; please translate or remove them the next time):

```c
    int socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    /*...*/

    fd_set base_rdset;
    fd_set rdset;

    /*...*/

    FD_SET(socket_fd, &base_rdset);
    while (1) {
        FD_ZERO(&rdset);
        memcpy(&rdset, &base_rdset, sizeof(base_rdset));
        int ready_num = select(10, &rdset, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

The two `fd_set`s are dynamic variables inside the function. Without explicit initialization of other means of defining their content, they hold undefined values. Commonly such variables live on the stack and its former content does not change if it is used for new variables.

The `FD_SET()` simply **adds** the given file descriptor to the existing set.

Inside the loop you initialize `rdset` with `FD_ZERO()`. But this has no effect, because the following `memcpy()` overrides it completely with the content of `base_rdset`.

And so `select()` receives a set of file descriptors you did not define. Some randomly set file descriptor triggers the error message.

Your last paragraph mentions the correct solution: Zero the set before you use it, this way:

```c
    fd_set base_rdset;

    /*...*/

    FD_ZERO(&base_rdset);
    FD_SET(socket_fd, &base_rdset);
```